# Sort a list in a list by numbers

Tags: python

I am in the process of creating a bot that will compare the price of many items. In the list I have the price with some other information. However, I would like to sort e.g. this list

```
['Soul String', 'RARE',  [900000, '3b4c1f7f9ae447a983817c303b62375a', 'Soul String'], [4000000, 'feacbc053bb240be954a4b17c14077d2', 'Soul String'], [4000000, 'feacbc053bb240be954a4b17c14077d2', 'Soul String'], [700000, '01b6b2ec8a5c4a4e934149a33e99802e', 'Soul String'], [700000, 'be1aa3a0700b403898a2e6e05d77e63d', 'Soul String']]
```

by the price, so it looks like this list

```
['Soul String', 'RARE', [4000000, 'feacbc053bb240be954a4b17c14077d2', 'Soul String'], [4000000, 'feacbc053bb240be954a4b17c14077d2', 'Soul String'], [700000, '01b6b2ec8a5c4a4e934149a33e99802e', 'Soul String'], [700000, 'be1aa3a0700b403898a2e6e05d77e63d', 'Soul String']], [900000, '3b4c1f7f9ae447a983817c303b62375a', 'Soul String']
```

But I have no clue how i can manage this, maybe one of you guys can help me

Comment: okay first can you clarify what is that hash and integer , if you specify more information we can provide you accurate answer to you.

Comment: Your expected list isn't a sorted list, the values are 4*10^6, 9*10^5 and 7*10^5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can custom sort via lambda:

```
l = ['Soul String', 'RARE',  [900000, '3b4c1f7f9ae447a983817c303b62375a', 'Soul String'], [4000000, 'feacbc053bb240be954a4b17c14077d2', 'Soul String'], [4000000, 'feacbc053bb240be954a4b17c14077d2', 'Soul String'], [700000, '01b6b2ec8a5c4a4e934149a33e99802e', 'Soul String'], [700000, 'be1aa3a0700b403898a2e6e05d77e63d', 'Soul String']]

sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0] if type(x[0])==int else 999999999, reverse=True)

['Soul String',
 'RARE',
 [4000000, 'feacbc053bb240be954a4b17c14077d2', 'Soul String'],
 [4000000, 'feacbc053bb240be954a4b17c14077d2', 'Soul String'],
 [900000, '3b4c1f7f9ae447a983817c303b62375a', 'Soul String'],
 [700000, '01b6b2ec8a5c4a4e934149a33e99802e', 'Soul String'],
 [700000, 'be1aa3a0700b403898a2e6e05d77e63d', 'Soul String']]
```

Please note that your current format is not ideal, because you are mixing the data. You could consider using a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'Soul String': {'name': 'Soul String', 'rarity': 'RARE',  'stock': [[900000, '3b4c1f7f9ae447a983817c303b62375a', 'Soul String'], [4000000, 'feacbc053bb240be954a4b17c14077d2', 'Soul String'], [4000000, 'feacbc053bb240be954a4b17c14077d2', 'Soul String'], [700000, '01b6b2ec8a5c4a4e934149a33e99802e', 'Soul String'], [700000, 'be1aa3a0700b403898a2e6e05d77e63d', 'Soul String']]}}

d['Soul String']['stock'] = sorted(d['Soul String']['stock'], key = lambda x: x[0], reverse = True)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need your list to be printed in reverse (from maximum value to minimum), you need to give your non-list elements the max value possible (that is, `math.inf`).

Then you can obtain your list `sorted` and in `reverse`, if you give as `key` the custom function defined.

```py
>>> import math
>>> def sort_list(element):
...    if isinstance(element, (list, tuple)): 
...       return element[0]
...    else: 
...       return math.inf

>>> sorted(l, key=sort_list, reverse=True)
['Soul String',
 'RARE',
 [4000000, 'feacbc053bb240be954a4b17c14077d2', 'Soul String'],
 [4000000, 'feacbc053bb240be954a4b17c14077d2', 'Soul String'],
 [900000, '3b4c1f7f9ae447a983817c303b62375a', 'Soul String'],
 [700000, '01b6b2ec8a5c4a4e934149a33e99802e', 'Soul String'],
 [700000, 'be1aa3a0700b403898a2e6e05d77e63d', 'Soul String']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a [list.sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method that allows custom sorting.

You could for example check if the current element is also a list and if so, sort it by its number. Otherwise, let it be there where it is.